# Had Jesus already read the end of the book?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Was Jesus aware of his ultimate destiny while on earth?  Did he already know that he would die, be resurrected, and reign as king in heaven while on earth as a man?  If so, does that not diminish the sacrificial intensity of the act?  How many of us would be much better equipped to handle suffering if we have already read the end of the book?  I am a god-fearing person and not trying to prove or disprove anything. I just really want to know the answer to this question backed up by scripture.

Comment: the opposite is true. Even though he knew he still gave his life. Many of us would run away from it as we do when we sin. We know the sin but still keep sinning.

Comment: Jesus sweated blood in the Garden of Gethsemane. The burden of sin placed on Him was so great that His weakened human nature shrank from it. He asked  "My Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me". This was the reality of the horror, but by faith and self-sacrificing love He overcame.

Answer (score 4):

If you believe that the Gospels are true, as most Christians do, then the answer is absolutely yes.  Jesus clearly knew not only about his death, but also about his resurrection and glorification.  This can be shown with several different passages, but even just this one passage sums it up rather clearly:

[Luke 9:21-26 (NASB)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=+Luke+9%3A21%E2%80%9326&version=NASB)

> But He warned them and instructed them not to tell this to anyone, saying, “The Son of Man **must suffer many things and be rejected by the elders and chief priests and scribes, and be killed and be raised up on the third day**.” And He was saying to them all, “If anyone wishes to come after Me, he must deny himself, and **take up his cross daily and follow Me**. For whoever wishes to save his life will lose it, but whoever loses his life for My sake, he is the one who will save it. For what is a man profited if he gains the whole world, and loses or forfeits himself? For whoever is ashamed of Me and My words, **the Son of Man will be ashamed of him when He comes in His glory**, and the glory of the Father and of the holy angels.

I suspect, however, that you have a misconceived presumption.  You seem to be assuming that the physical pain and shame of the crucifixion was the sum total of the suffering that Jesus had to endure.  Most Christians would tell you that the physical crucifixion was only a small part of the actual suffering.  The larger suffering was spiritual in nature.  Jesus [became sin](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%205%3A21&version=NASB).  He did so to provide [propitiation for our sins](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%202:2&version=NASB).

The spiritual aspect of the Christ's suffering was, of course prophesied years before Jesus was born:

[Isaiah 53:11-12 (NASB)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=is%2053%3A11-12&version=NASB)

> As a result of the anguish of His soul,
> He will see it and be satisfied;
> By His knowledge the Righteous One,
> My Servant, will justify the many,
> As He will bear their iniquities.
> Therefore, I will allot Him a portion with the great,
> And He will divide the booty with the strong;
> Because He poured out Himself to death,
> And was numbered with the transgressors;
> Yet He Himself bore the sin of many,
> And interceded for the transgressors.

The great distress that Jesus felt because of his knowledge of his coming suffering was most evident when he prayed in the Garden of Gethsemane.  You can read about that event in [Matthew 26:36-46](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026%3A36-46&version=NASB), [Mark 14:32-42](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2014%3A32-42&version=NASB), and [Luke 22:39-46](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026%3A36-46&version=NASB).